# Text from Contentful came out as one single paragraph

Tags: markdown, nuxt.js, contentful

I am doing a website using Nuxt.js and Contentful to show a list of courses. I have created a content model for courses on Contentful. Each course has a description. When I retrieve the description on Nuxt.js, the text comes out in one single paragraph. I want to show some formatting, at least line breaks. The text, apparently, can show markdown tags, - Is there any package, functionality, etc. that I can use to convert those tags to HTML? Thanks.

I have made the description just text but I also tried using Rich Text with the same output, all text in one line.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this.

- Add @nuxtjs/markdownit ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/markdownit) as a dependency of the project like `npm install @nuxtjs/markdownit --save`
- Add it to modules on the nuxt.config.file and add this config for markdown

```
modules: [
  '@nuxtjs/markdownit'
],
markdownit: {
  injected: true
},
```

- Finally, on the page for the course.
  `<div v-html="$md.render(course.fields.fulldescription)"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

If you use [rich text react renderer](https://github.com/contentful/rich-text/tree/master/packages/rich-text-react-renderer) with the Rich Text field, you can define custom rendering for your text nodes using the following line in options:

```
const options = {
 renderText: text => text.split('\n').flatMap((text, i) => [i > 0 && <br />, 
 text])
}
```

This will find and replace \n with 
 in your text nodes.